# Prevent MyST from changing .md image paths

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen, read-the-docs, myst

I'm generating sphinx documentation with.md files that reference images via relative paths:

`![](../_static/figures/image.png)`

I use MyST to parse the .md files into html, but it removes the `../'` making all paths:

`_static/figures/image.png`.

The relative paths work fine before documentation generation and has to kept the same.
In the `conf.py` for sphinx I copy over the images as `html_static_path` files, and if the path is kept the same in the html, the images would show.

The [MyST docs](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#syntax-images) state that it copies .md images but give no configuration options for copying. The paragraphs below only reference how to parse HTML files with images. I did find [another option](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#:%7E:text=myst_all_links_external,default%3A%20False:%7E:text=myst_all_links_external,default%3A%20False) that should treat all links as hyperlinks, but this made no change.

How do I force MyST to not change the image paths?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more of a convention question.

It is recommended to put `_static` in all folder levels and separate assets like images inside each of them, so that links like `_static/figures/image.png` resolve to just that folder level.

If you want to use a single top level `_static` folder for all folder levels, then your links should be written as `/_static/figures/image.png`, where they are resolved to the top level.

Comment: I like both your conventions and would implement one; unfortunately the relative paths must be kept the same. I'm wondering if there is a setting within MyST to not parse paths/links.